# Increase depth of OpenGL Attribute stack

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to increase the attribute stack depth in OpenGL?

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_ATTRIB_STACK_DEPTH, &depth);
```

returns depth as being 16. Can I change `GL_MAX_STACK_DEPTH` to, for example, 32?

Comment: You can cache these yourself

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I don't believe the OP wants to speed up access to these constants, but change them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This is a driver/hardware limitation.